# The faster way is string chars extraction

Tags: python

I am receiving string data from a data stream.

Data (string) format example:

```
data = "#T:50,100"
```

I need to extract the digits 50 and 100.

Currently I do it like this:

```
X = int(data[3:].split(",")[0])
Y = int(data[3:].split(",")[1])
```

The data stream is very fast, I receive a lot of this data on a device with very low computing power and small memory. The code I provided uses a lot of memory, can it be done faster?

Comment: Memory usage and speed of execution are not necessarily related to each other. Which are you looking to optimize? What have you tried in support of said optimizations?

Comment: "*The code I provided uses a lot of memory*" I recognize the term "*a lot*" is highly subjective, but I have a hard time believing this code here actually uses anything even remotely resembling a material amount of memory. Can you share how you reached this conclusion, and what benchmarks you've run on this code specifically that support this assertion of yours? If you need to run in a highly-constrained embedded-style context, why choose Python or any interpreted language over a compiled language?

Comment: A simple optimization is not to do the slice/split twice: `x, y = [int(n) for n in data[3:].split(',')]`.

Comment: @esqew memory usage...

Comment: It shouldn't use lots of memory. Each assignment creates a few small temporary strings and a list, but they'll be GCed immediately after the variable is assigned.

Comment: Python uses reference counts for its basic GC mechanism. Since there are no reference loops in the temporaries, this should be extremely effective and efficient here. The problem is most likely somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @MarkTolonen perhaps `X, Y = map(int, data[3:].split(','))` if we are micro-optimizing. but I too am skeptical this is any sort of memory bottleneck.